# Does git specify recursive behaviour for gitignore patterns?

Tags: git, gitignore

This is the exact question as [Where is gitignore recursive behavior specified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31461236/where-is-gitignore-recursive-behavior-specified), because I do not think its accepted answer explains what in git's documentation specifies the recursive behaviour of gitignore patterns.

Consider the following scenario. The structure of the repository is

```
.gitignore
a
|
-- f
```

(that is, at the root of the repository there is a `.gitignore` file and a folder named `a`, and inside `a` there is a file named `f`)

The `.gitignore` file at the root of the repository contains `f` as the only pattern.

Now if we were to read the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore), we would find the following paragrah (emphasis mine):

> If the pattern does not contain a slash /, Git treats it as a shell glob pattern and **checks for a match against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file** (relative to the toplevel of the work tree if not from a .gitignore file).

From the paragraph quoted above I understand that when `git` checks whether file `f` should be ignored or not, it would try to match its "**pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file**" to the pattern. Therefore, it would try to match the pattern `f` with `a/f`, which should not match.

Is my understanding not correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're misreading the bolded phrase (which I admit is easy to do—Git documentation often leaves something to be desired).

What the phrase "relative to the location of the .gitignore file" is *attempting* to convey is this idea:

```
.gitignore
bar
dir/
    dir/.gitignore
    dir/bar
    dir/hello
foo
hello
```

Suppose that `.gitignore` consists of the line `hello`, while `dir/.gitignore` consists of the line `bar`.  The file `hello` in *both* directories is ignored, because `hello` is ignored at the top level, but the file `bar` in the top directory is *not* ignored, because `bar` is ignored by `dir/.gitignore`, which affects only files in `dir` and subdirectories of `dir`.

#### Asides

1. The stuff about slashes in the patterns in `.gitignore` entries is particularly tricky.  The documentation says that a (single) trailing slash is removed temporary to make the decision: *does this entry contain a slash?*  Then it's put back.  I think a better way to phrase this—not that Git does so—is to say: "An entry is *rooted* if and only if it contains a slash that is not the last character in the entry."  This "rooting" idea means that the full (relative-to-`.gitignore`-location) path name must match.  Otherwise the pattern will match in both that directory and all of its subdirectories, which is more or less the same issue you're looking at here.
2. Remember that `.gitignore` doesn't really mean *ignore*.  It mostly means *don't complain about untracked files.*

   Files are *tracked* if and only if they are in Git's *index*.  The contents of the index change over time—they're initially "whatever was in the commit you just checked out", but you can replace files that are in it, or put new ones into it, with `git add`, and you can remove files from it with `git rm` (or, for that matter, with `git add`!).  If a file *is* tracked—i.e., if that file's name is in the index *right now*—then any matching of that file's name to any `.gitignore` entry is entirely irrelevant.
3. Only *files* are ever tracked.  Because of this fact, a `.gitignore` entry for a directory is, well, weird.  A directory is *never* going to be tracked.  The effect a directory name in a `.gitignore` is, correspondingly, especially weird and tricky.

   The internal, performance-oriented goal of ignoring an entire directory in Git is not so much "to make things easier for the user to express" as, instead, "to make Git go really fast, like a racecar that you can drive at 700 mph over a cliff!"

   One of the slower parts of Git is enumerating, one file at a time, every file and sub-directory and all the sub-directories' files *within* some directory, because Git has to keep asking the OS, one file at a time, *about* each of those files (make `lstat` system calls).  The Git folks observed that if you could, somehow, tell Git: *don't even **look inside** the `vendor` directory*, you could skip the thousands of SDK files that you dropped in there, making `git status` so very much faster.

   To that end, if you list `vendor` or `vendor/` (or `/vendor/` to root the pattern to the directory holding the `.gitignore` file), *and* Git's index has *no* files named `vendor/anything` in it, *then*—and only then—Git can skip right over the `vendor` directory and not bother enumerating the thousands of SDK files.

   On the other hand, if you list `vendor/*` or `/vendor/*`—both of these mean the same thing since both contain a `/` that is not the final `/`—Git *will* have to open and read the `vendor` directory.  Whether or not all ten thousand files (and/or subdirectories) are in the top level of that directory, Git will be able to skip them—they match `vendor/*` after all—but it will first have to *enumerate* at least the top level of the `vendor` directory.  This enumeration process gives you the chance to then *un*-ignore any particular sub-directory or file, such as `vendor/REMEMBER_WHICH_VERSION_WE_GOT` (though it's probably better to remember that *outside* the vendor sub-tree).

   (Note that once there's a tracked file in some directory, Git is obligated to look inside that directory, even if the directory is nominally ignored.  So this make-the-race-car-go-fast-even-if-there's-a-cliff-nearby trick only applies when there are no tracked files in there, i.e., forcing Git to track a file makes sure there's no cliff either, in this rather twisted analogy.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In general I know how gitignore patterns work in practice, I just have a problem with their documentation. The only correct way in which I could interpret the bolded section is: try to match the pattern (f) against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file (a/f). Why would they use pathname there? Why not say something like: "and checks for a match against the filename of each tested file"? That coupled with the explanation of how .gitignore files are searched (directory of the tested file, its parent, its parent's parent, ...) should be enough.

Comment: So you are trying to say that they used "against the pathname relative to the location of the .gitignore file" in order to say that only files and folders **under** this location are affected? But I could write the path of the top-level bar file "relative to the location of the .gitignore file" like this: "../bar".

Comment: I agree that the wording is not good. That's why I use the word *rooted* instead. But I can't correct their documentation...